# CSS Floats On Same Line Variable Amount

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout, css-float

I want to have horizontal lists that can run as wide as possible but within a fixed width container. I am using jQuery to allow scrolling on the really wide list, and overflow:automatic for users without javascript.

I have code along the lines of this:

```
<div class="list"> 
    <ul> 
        <li class="feed"> 
            <section> 
                <h1><span class="name">Title</span></h1> 
                <div class="scroll_left"><a class="ir" href="#">Scroll Back</a></div> 
                <div class="article_list"> 
                    <ul class="article_list"> 
                        <li> 
                            <a href="article.php"> 
                                <div class="article_thumb"><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt="blah" /></div> 
                                <h2>Title of article</h2> 
                            </a> 
                        </li> 
                        <li> 
                            <a href="article.php"> 
                                <div class="article_thumb"><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt="blah" /></div> 
                                <h2>Title of article</h2> 
                            </a> 
                        </li> 
                        <li> 
                            <a href="article.php"> 
                                <div class="article_thumb"><img src="img/placeholder.png" alt="blah" /></div> 
                                <h2>Title of article</h2> 
                            </a> 
                        </li>
                        <!-- variable number of li's, from 10s to 100s -->
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </section>
        </li>
        <!-- More of these lists -->
    </ul>
</div>
```

I'll just give a subset of my css that I think is relevant:

```
.feed .article_list {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    float: left;
    width: 900px;
}

.feed .article_list ul {
    position: relative;
    width: 10000px; /** I want this to be wide, but not allow scrolling past the end*/
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
}

.feed .article_list li {
    display: block;
    width: 130px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    border-right: 2px solid #b5e8f4;
    border-left: 2px solid #b5e8f4;
    margin: 0 5px 0 0;
}
```

My javascript is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('div.article_list').css({
        'overflow' : 'hidden'
    });

    $('.scroll_left a').click(function() {
        toScroll = $(this).parent().next();
        toScroll.animate({scrollLeft: "-=135"});
        return false;
    });

    $('.scroll_right a').click(function() {
        toScroll = $(this).parent().prev();
        toScroll.animate({scrollLeft: "+=135"});
        return false;
    });

});
```

So as it is, I either have to make the inner ul really wide, so users can scroll well beyond the list items, or I can restrict it but if I add too many items (dynamically, so I don't have a lot of control), then the layout breaks.

Can I somehow get that scrollable area to just be as wide as its floated contents?
Or is the only solution to set the width in javascript (less than ideal, but I can do that)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its the `float: left` on the `.feed .article_list` that you really don't want but I've removed it from all of them that I could.

I would move to an inline setup instead of floating:

```
.feed .article_list {
    position: relative;
    overflow: auto;
    width: 100%; /* specify what ever width you want. I think 100% is proper. */
}

.feed .article_list ul {
    position: relative;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

By making the `overflow-x:  scroll` you have a permanent scroll bar (not totally necessary, it can be removed if you prefer). The `white-space: nowrap` Will keep the children on one line (instead of floating.)

```
.feed .article_list li {
    display: inline-block;
    // etc. etc. etc. ...
```

on the children `display: inline-block;` will let you specify height/width like a block element and keep them inline at the same time.

**JsFiddle:-** http://jsfiddle.net/GBtCb/

**UPDATE :-**

In an effort to make it cross-browser compatible make the following changes:
remove the `overflow: auto` from `.feed .article_list`
 and add:

```
.feed
{
    overflow: hidden;
}
.article_list
{
    overflow: auto;
```

from quirksmode.com:

- http://www.quirksmode.org/css/whitespace.html : `white-space: nowrap` is compatible IE7+.
  -

Comment: Thank you! Now what is the browser support for this? I am okay with abandoning IE6 and old browsers, but I would like this to work in modern browsers. I can test on my own time unless you have an answer off hand.

Comment: @Matt um ... browser suppor ... I usually only worry about IE8+ (as XP can't go higher). I've added an update that i think should make it more cross browser. But no promises. sorry.

Comment: @Matt initial test didn't work in IE7. If you want to support IE7 http://jsfiddle.net/GBtCb/3/ The difference in this one compared to your original is the removal of `float: left` on the `.feed .article_list` and `overflow-x: scroll` on `.article_list ul`